# Question on two equivalent densities

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, finance

I have two integrals $I_1$ and $I_2$ that are almost similar :
$$I_1=\int_K^{+\infty}(x-K)f_1(x)dx$$ $$I_2=\int_K^{+\infty}(x-K)f_2(x)dx$$ with$f_1$ and $f_2$ being two equivalent densities (so they are always positive or null, both integrate to 1 over their domain, and are "good" functions :their limit value when x goes to $-\infty$ or to $+\infty$ is null).

What conditions must respect $f_1$ and $f_2$ to have $I_1 < I_2$ whatever the value of K is ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question, why not $f_2(x)=f_1(x-c)$ where $c\gt 0$?

Comment: your proposal assumes that we may write $f_2(x)=f_1(x-c)$ which means the second function is a kind of translation of the first one. It's a special case of the question. In that specific case, depending on the value of $c$, you have either $I_1<I_2$ or the inverse. unfortunately, i want a more general result....

Comment: As long as $f_1(x)\gt 0$ for all $x$, $I_1\lt I_2$  $I_2=\int_K^\infty(x-K)f_1(x-c)dx=\int_{K-c}^\infty (c+y-K)f_1(y)dy=I_1+\int_{K-c}^K(c+y-K)f_1(y)dy+c\int_K^\infty f_1(y)dy\gt I_1$

Comment: My proposal is certainly sufficient ($c\gt 0$).  I haven't looked at possible necessary conditions.

Comment: Equivalency of $f_1$ and $f_2$ doesn't mean these functions may be restrictedto the case where $f_2(x)=f_1(x-c)$... Or do i misunderstand something... Take for example the  density of a Student Law and the density of a normal law, they are equivalent in the probabilistic sense but they don't respect your translation property...

Comment: I was just creating an example.  They aren't restricted.  A more general case, let $G(u)$ be any distribution function (which is zero for $u\le 0)$, then any$f_2(x)=\int_0^\infty f_1(x-u)dG(u)$. will do.

Comment: If you want a necessary condition, I don't have an answer.